# Strings in Python 3

Tags: python, unicode, string, python-3.x, ctypes

I am programing [VIX API](http://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vix-api/) from python 2.5, but now I want to port the code to python 3.2

This function opens the virtual machine:

```
self.jobHandle = self.VixLib.vix.VixVM_Open(self.hostHandle,
                                            "C:\\MyVirtualMachine.vmx", None, None)
```

Previusly this function is imported from Vix.dll with this code:

```
vix.VixVM_Open.restype = VixHandle
vix.VixVM_Open.argtypes = [VixHandle,c_char_p,POINTER(VixEventProc),c_void_p]
```

In 2.5 this code is correct, but in 3.2 it returns `ctypes.ArgumentError`

What can I do?

Comment: I'm guessing this is related to the fact that all strings went unicode in 3.0, but I don't know what the solution is.

Comment: Including the whole stack trace might be useful.

Comment: what is whole stack trace???sorry but I´m begginer in python

Comment: It's everything the interpreter dumps out to you when it hits an exception (everything surrounding the "ArgumentError")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your second argument has to be encoded to a format that the VIX API will understand, since Python 3.x now creates all strings as Unicode.  The simplest approach would be to modify your second argument to read:

```
"C:\\MyVirtualMachine.vmx".encode('ascii','ignore')
```

which should give you a variable of type bytes, which should be more palatable to VIX.

Comment: Making this the problem was soluted!! thank you very much!! where can I vote you???